# Automatically prompt to update default site domain name when running Django’s ./manage.py syncdb?

Tags: python, django, django-sites

Regarding Django Sites module and manage.py syncdb

The Auth module can prompt to ask for default superuser for the admin site, during .\manage.py syncdb. I would like to see similar things happen for the default site domain name. Currently it is example.com, hardcoded unless I use admin web site to change it. I want to change it during syncdb.

Answer (score 6):

I made a small django app that can be plugged in and play. To plug it in:

2. download it into project directory or into where your project can find.
3. add, in your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS, "site_default" (the app name) at the end or after "django.contrib.sites" that it depends on.
4. Run `manage.py syncdb` 
   or `manage.py createdefaultsite`

Screen shot:

```
(pinax-dev)>manage.py createdefaultsite
Site domain name: mydomain.com
Site display name: My Site!
(pinax-dev)
```

It comes with a unit test.
To run unit test:

```
(pinax-dev)>manage.py test site_default
```

"site_default" is the app name.

Source code:
[http://github.com/peiwei/pinax/raw/master/pinax/apps/site_default.tgz](http://github.com/peiwei/pinax/tree/master/pinax/apps/site_default/)

More Screenshot:

```
(pinax-dev)> manage.py syncdb
Creating table...
You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superuse
rs defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username: administrator
E-mail address: who@who.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.

Would you like to change the default site domain name? (yes/no)[default:no]: yes

Site domain name: mydomain.com
Site display name: My Site!
...
Installing index for signup_codes.SignupCode model
Installing index for signup_codes.SignupCodeResult model
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this yourself:

1. Create a management command to prompt for your new site
2. connect it to the `post_syncdb` signal

The command will let you set the site conveniently from the command line. Connecting it to the signal will mean you get prompted whenever the `sites` app is installed. eg:

```
from django.contrib.sites import models as sites_app
signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_site, sender=sites_app)
```

When writing the `create_site` function (signal handler), you can copy the `auth` module's approach almost exactly:

```
def create_site(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.core.management import call_command
if Site in created_models and kwargs.get('interactive', True):
    msg = "\nYou just installed Django's sites system, which means you don't have " \
            "any sites defined.\nWould you like to create one now? (yes/no): "
    confirm = raw_input(msg)
    while 1:
        if confirm not in ('yes', 'no'):
            confirm = raw_input('Please enter either "yes" or "no": ')
            continue
        if confirm == 'yes':
            call_command("createsite", interactive=True)
        break
```

Now you just need to create your management command `createsite` and you're done. I do wonder why this isn't already in Django though, I hate example.com.

Put all this into a little app and reuse it for every project your do. Bonus points if you post the app somewhere like google code or django's bug tracker.